# What is the limit (if any) to the tuple cardinality in Swift?

Tags: tuples, swift

Each tuple cardinality is represented by its own type in swift (as in any other strongly-typed programming language I'm aware of), so we have

```
($T1, $T2)
($T1, $T2, $T3)
...
```

Since we have several different types, one per cardinality, they need to be finite.

In Scala we have up to `Tuple22`, in Haskell the current limit should be 64.

What's the limit (if any) in swift? Also, are the types implementations generated by the compiler or is there an explicit implementation I couldn't find?

Comment: I think the WWDC video says that there isn't a limit. I'll try to get an exact quote.

Comment: I don't think there is something mentioned in apple Swift book about tuple limit. The one thing I remember is that tuples are not suited to the creation of complex data structures in that case you should use class or structure.

Comment: Actually it's not true that you have a different type for each cardinality. You have a different type for each ... tuple type. A tuple of two `Int`s has a different type than a tuple of two `Double`s, even if they have the same cardinality. A tuple type is in fact an extension of a product type to higher cardinalities in the same sense that a tuple is an extension of an ordered pair to higher cardinalities.

Comment: @AnalogFile I'll do here the same observation I did in another answer: `Tuple2` is a polymorphic type. `Tuple2<Int, Int>` is a concrete type. Still types though.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Nope. I replied in more details to your other comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429455/underlying-type-for-tuple-in-swift/24431787#comment37820394_24431787

Comment: Ok, `Tuple2<T1,T2>` is a polymorphic type, `Tuple2<Int, Int>` is a concrete type. My point still holds: you have a (polymorphic) type for each tuple cardinality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the current version of Xcode 6 Beta, compilation fails with tuples of arity larger than 1948 (the `swift` executable exits with code 254; there isn't a specific warning or error).

Comment: thanks, I tried up to a few hundreds, then I wondered whether a limit existed at all. That's nice to know, thanks.

Comment: I suppose this limit will change in future releases, so maybe this answer will need updating.

Comment: But for example `Equality` is only implemented by default for tuples with 6 or less components.